# Http request retorna ZoneAwarePromise

Tags: angular

Criei um service para executar as solitações GET / POST / DELETE e PUT. Quando faço o primeiro request recebo ZoneAwarePromise no corpo da mensagem. Como acessar os dados dentro do ZoneAwarePromise ou alterar o meu código para não retornar o ZoneAwarePromise?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Abaixo o GET dentro do service

```
  public get(url: string) {
    const header = this.createHeader();

    return new Promise(async(resolve) => {
      try {
        const result = this._HttpClient.get(url, { headers: header }).toPromise();
        resolve({ success: true, data: result, error: undefined });
      } catch (error) {
        resolve({ success: false, data: {}, error });
      }
    }); 
  }
```

Aqui o meu request dentro do component.

```
this._HttpService.get(`${ServerUrl.ApiUrl}MarkingGet`).then(data => console.log(data));
```

Comment: Não entendi, pq envolveu o *get* em uma `Promise`? Alíás deveria ir na documentação do **`Angular`** e ver como faz um service get e como consome, não tem nada a ver com isso aí. Só para ter uma ideia o Angular utiliza **Observables** e para a chamada do método utiliza **subscribe**.

Comment: @LeAndrade a idéia é criar um service e diminuir a quantidade de códigos repetidos. Mas de qualquer jeito irei sim dar uma lida na documentação

Answer (score 0):

Achei um documento explicando como fazer a requisição, muito bom para iniciantes como eu.

https://www.techiediaries.com/angular/angular-9-8-tutorial-by-example-rest-crud-apis-http-get-requests-with-httpclient/

No service

```
 handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse) {
        let errorMessage = 'Unknown error!';
        if (error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
          // Client-side errors
          errorMessage = `Error client: ${error.error.message}`;
        } else {
          // Server-side errors
          errorMessage = `Error server: ${error.status}\nMessage: ${error.message}`;
        }
        window.alert(errorMessage);
        return throwError(errorMessage);
}    

 public get(url: string) {
   const header = this.createHeader();
    
   return this._HttpClient.get(url, { headers: header }).pipe(catchError(this.handleError));
 }
```

No componente

```
this._HttpService.get(`${ServerUrl.ApiUrl}MarkingGet`).subscribe(data => {
   this.result = data;

   console.log(this.result);
})
```